# Do temporary agencies tend to act differently before and after hiring someone?

Tags: professionalism, communication, ethics

I have a question about temporary agencies.

I was hired by an agency to work at an assignment. Towards the end of my assignment (about 2 months before the end date), I got a family emergency and must quit the assignment. And the problem started right from here.

So this agency is located in the other city. All the paperwork for this assignment was basically done electronically. I only talked to one of the agents a few times on the phone before I was hired. Later, when I got this emergency, I had tried to call the agency without success. I switched to sending them an email explaining the situation, which I received a line from them saying "Okay".

During the time when I was taking care of my family, the agency sent an email notifying me an automatic enrollment into their benefits package. And lots of chaos were created. It almost cut off the insurance coverage for me and my family at the time when we were actively going in and out the hospital. But this is another story.

I couldn't go into their office since it is located in another city and I was not free to go anywhere with the given condition of my family. So the only way to communicate with them was through email. And it is still true up to this point.

But I feel really annoyed with the agency. It rarely gives me a reply. Even they do, they only reply with a phone number asking me to call them. All 4 numbers I received from them are not working at all! I had tried to call the agency many times, but the lines always seemed to be busy for some reason.

I got a similar experience with another temporary agency too.
It's like they don't care about you once you have signed a contract with them. I feel used by these temporary agencies, but I'm not sure what they can get from me.

**Do temporary agencies tend to act differently before and after hiring someone?**

Answer (score 4):

> Towards the end of my assignment (about 2 months before the end date), I got a family emergency and must quit the assignment

Your problem right there,  you no longer earn them commission, so they've lost interest (plus you're using benefits by sound of it).

You only matter as long as you earn them money, which is why when you find a rare one that isn't like that you stick with them.

They'll come around when and if you become a prospect for another role.

Comment: +1 Pretty much all there is to say.  Never expect ANY employer to be your friend, they are out to help themselves, not to help you unless you are helping them.

Comment: Just like recruiters, the temp agency's job is to fill open positions.  If you arent filling a position, any relationship with you is costing them time and therefore, money.